# How to save data take from the use in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, native

I am using react native and, i want to take input from user and store in react native state variable and display on the screen.

Comment: Nothing like good old [Official Documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html) to teach you how to use a platform/library/etc... See also [Handling input](https://reactnative.dev/docs/handling-text-input).

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should start reading the [official documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/getting-started), this will help you to start with the basics. However, [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput) is the answer to your question.